# ThreadPoolExecutor policy

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, executor, blockingqueue

I'm trying to use a ThreadPoolExecutor to schedule tasks, but running into some problems with its policies. Here's its stated behavior:

1. If fewer than corePoolSize threads are running, the Executor always prefers adding a new thread rather than queuing.
2. If corePoolSize or more threads are running, the Executor always prefers queuing a request rather than adding a new thread.
3. If a request cannot be queued, a new thread is created unless this would exceed maximumPoolSize, in which case, the task will be rejected.

The behavior I want is this:

1. same as above
2. If more than corePoolSize but less than maximumPoolSize threads are running, prefers adding a new thread over queuing, and using an idle thread over adding a new thread.
3. same as above

Basically I don't want any tasks to be rejected; I want them to be queued in an unbounded queue. But I do want to have up to maximumPoolSize threads. If I use an unbounded queue, it never generates threads after it hits coreSize. If I use a bounded queue, it rejects tasks. Is there any way around this?

What I'm thinking about now is running the ThreadPoolExecutor on a SynchronousQueue, but not feeding tasks directly to it - instead feeding them to a separate unbounded LinkedBlockingQueue. Then another thread feeds from the LinkedBlockingQueue into the Executor, and if one gets rejected, it simply tries again until it is not rejected. This seems like a pain and a bit of a hack, though - is there a cleaner way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your use case is common, completely legit and unfortunately more difficult than one would expect. For background info you can read [this discussion](http://cs.oswego.edu/pipermail/concurrency-interest/2010-June/007176.html) and find a pointer to a solution (also mentioned in the thread) [here](http://www.kimchy.org/juc-executorservice-gotcha/). Shay's solution works fine.

Generally I'd be a bit wary of unbounded queues; it's usually better to have explicit incoming flow control that degrades gracefully and regulates the ratio of current/remaining work to not overwhelm either producer or consumer.

Answer (score 4):

It probably isn't necessary to micro-manage the thread pool as being requested.

A cached thread pool will re-use idle threads while also allowing potentially unlimited concurrent threads. This of course could lead to runaway performance degrading from context switching overhead during bursty periods.

```
Executors.newCachedThreadPool();
```

A better option is to place a limit on the total number of threads while discarding the notion of ensuring idle threads are used first. The configuration changes would be:

```
corePoolSize = maximumPoolSize = N;
allowCoreThreadTimeOut(true);
setKeepAliveTime(aReasonableTimeDuration, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

Reasoning over this scenario, if the executor has less than `corePoolSize` threads, than it must not be very busy. If the system is not very busy, then there is little harm in spinning up a new thread. Doing this will cause your `ThreadPoolExecutor` to always create a new worker if it is under the maximum number of workers allowed. Only when the maximum number of workers are "running" will workers waiting idly for tasks be given tasks. If a worker waits `aReasonableTimeDuration` without a task, then it is allowed to terminate. Using reasonable limits for the pool size (after all, there are only so many CPUs) and a reasonably large timeout (to keep threads from needlessly terminating), the desired benefits will likely be seen.

The final option is hackish. Basically, the `ThreadPoolExecutor` internally uses `BlockingQueue.offer` to determine if the queue has capacity. A custom implementation of `BlockingQueue` could always reject the `offer` attempt. When the `ThreadPoolExecutor` fails to `offer` a task to the queue, it will try to make a new worker. If a new worker can not be created, a `RejectedExecutionHandler` would be called. At that point, a custom `RejectedExecutionHandler` could force a `put` into the custom `BlockingQueue`.

```
/** Hackish BlockingQueue Implementation tightly coupled to ThreadPoolexecutor implementation details. */
class ThreadPoolHackyBlockingQueue<T> implements BlockingQueue<T>, RejectedExecutionHandler {
    BlockingQueue<T> delegate;

    public boolean offer(T item) {
        return false;
    }

    public void rejectedExecution(Runnable r, ThreadPoolExecutor executor) {
        delegate.put(r);
    }

    //.... delegate methods
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just set `corePoolsize = maximumPoolSize` and use an unbounded queue?

In your list of points, 1 excludes 2, since `corePoolSize` will always be less or equal than `maximumPoolSize`.

**Edit**

There is still something incompatible between what you want and what TPE will offer you.

If you have an unbounded queue, `maximumPoolSize` is ignored so, as you observed, no more than `corePoolSize` threads will ever be created and used.

So, again, if you take `corePoolsize = maximumPoolSize` with an unbounded queue, you have what you want, no?

Comment: Oops, what I wrote wasn't exactly what I wanted. I edited the original.

Comment: Setting corePoolsize = maximumPoolSize is indeed close, but I'm also using allowCoreThreadTimeOut(false) and prestartAllCoreThreads().

Answer (score 1):

Would you be looking for something more like a cached thread pool?

http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Executors.html#newCachedThreadPool()